# Google Play store review, how to upload a demonstration video for reviewers

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

This is the app rejected error from Google Play console

```
Issues with submitted video

We were unable to view the video you provided in your declaration.

Your video should show the in-app feature’s functionality showing usage of location in the background, and how a user would trigger the prominent disclosure, runtime permission (with user consent), and feature in action.

Please check that your video is accessible, and/or modify your video to demonstrate the declared feature that requires access to location in the background then resubmit your declaration form via the Play Console.
```

I'm trying to find where I can upload or provide a link to demostration video for review, I'm not able to find

Can you please show me where can I provide a demo video for reviewers in google play console?

Answer (score 1):

As [Requesting access to location in the background](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-provide-a-video-demonstration) says:

You can now submit your app for feedback on location in the background access by completing the [Location permissions declaration form](https://play.google.com/console/developers/app/app-content/permission-declarations) in Play Console.

(Google Play Console -> select you application -> left side menu-> Policy -> App content -> Sensitive permissions and APIs -> Location permissions)
[image]